# 3rd argument is ignored when I use memcpy in C

Tags: memcpy, memset

I'm a beginner in C and try to use memcpy to send byte in order to transfer data to server. It seems like no matter what I choose for 3rd argument. It's always the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    
    char myChar[100] = "Hello world! ABC is an online sandbox that makes it easy to try out";
    char myChar2[100];
    
    memcpy(myChar2, myChar, 3);
    
    printf("%s", myChar);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result.

Hello world! ABC is an online sandbox that makes it easy to try out

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` is working correctly.
The problem with your code is that you are printing `myChar` instead of `myChar2`.

```
printf("%s", myChar2); // Hel
```

[Working example](https://ideone.com/cYAM8V)